# How to preserve whitespaces in attributes values when using XDocument?

Tags: .net, attributes, whitespace, linq-to-xml

I process xml which contains tabs ("\t") and line breaks ("\n") in its attributes values. When I parse it using XDocument.Parse(), the tabs and line breaks are converted to spaces, even with the LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace parameter.

How can I get a XDocument with original attributes values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a real solution, so I ended up with a quick & dirty :

```
xml = xml.Replace("\t", "&#x9;").Replace("\r", "&#xA;");
```

better than nothing...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple XmlTextReader to parse the xml-string. It will preserve all whitespace within attribute values:

```
string textToParse = "<e a=\"x\ty\rz\n\" />" ;
using (var sr = new StringReader(textToParse)) {
    using (var xr = new XmlTextReader(sr)) {
        var xd = XDocument.Load(xr);
        System.Console.WriteLine(xd.ToString());
    }
}
```

will output

```
<e a="x&#x9;y&#xD;z&#xA;" />
```